# How to use Pantheon File Manager to connect to Apple Time Capsule drive

Tags: pantheon-files, networking, files

I've setup my drive on time capsule and can successfully mount it manually with the following:

```
  mkdir ~/tcdrive
  sudo mount.cifs //MyTimeCapsule.local/Data ~/tcdrive/ -o username=myusername,sec=ntlm,password=mypassword
```

However, ideally I'd like able to access / browse to this network shared drive via the Pantheon FileManager directly (without manually mounting first using the above).

I've tried connecting to it using "Connect to Server" but can't seem to find a working set options.

I'm also unable to figure out how to do this Nautilus FileManager (which I setup so I could have desktop icons), so a solution for either Pantheon or Nautilus would work!